# Tensorflow could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0' in C++ project

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have installed [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) Linux GPU support

I have installed Cuda

I use [cppFlow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/tree/master/include/cppflow) library

And this all is at 23.04 ("Lunar Lobster") ubuntu

I have made a simle examle

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(tensorflowLearn)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(
        tensorflowLearn
        main.cpp
)

find_library(TENSORFLOW_LIBRARY tensorflow /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so)
find_library(TENSORFLOW_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY tensorflow_framework /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so)

target_link_libraries(
        tensorflowLearn
        LINK_PUBLIC
        ${TENSORFLOW_LIBRARY}
        ${TENSORFLOW_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
)
```

But I have a warning *Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'* and other libraries. Though I have a result *Hello from TensorFlow C library version 2.11.0*


I found my *cuda* directory in */usr/local* It is called **cuda-12.1**. I found all libraries I need there. But they have other numbers. For example I have **libcudart.so** files like that

> libcudart.so
> libcudart.so.12
> libcudart.so.12.1.105

I understand I should do something with tensorflow library but what? That is a question ))

Tell me please what I can do in this case?

Comment: There is a version mismatch. Your project wants CUDA 11 but you have CUDA 12 installed. That's what those numbers mean. Depending on your package manager you might be able to download CUDA 11 as well and export `$CUDA_HOME` to `/usr/local/cuda-11.XX` in your terminal session. Or just downgrade, but that could break other things that require CUDA 12.